# New Skype URIs for video calling is not working in IOS

Tags: ios, video, call, skype

I am IOS developer. I have developed one application which use Skype for voice calling and video calling. I can make a voice call through my application easily but in video call it's not working.

For video call:
 `skype:skypeUserName?call&video=true`

I am using new Skype URIs functionality.

Skype URIs :  https://developer.skype.com/skype-uris/reference

Please help me to solve this issue.

Many Thanks

Comment: try `skype://skypeUserName?call&video=true`

Answer (score 0):

It seems that currently even

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"skype:echo123?call"]];
```

which I brought from [official tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/dn745885%28v=office.15%29.aspx) is not working on current Skype iOS app version.